# Lexicographical Sorting of Word List

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I need to merge and sort lists of 100,000+ words lexicographically. I currently do it with a slightly modified bubble sort, but at O(n^2) it takes quite a while. Are there any faster algorithms for sorting lists of words? I'm using Python, but if there is a language that can handle this better I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: *in-place one that is if the memory is constrained

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any `O(nlogn)` [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) will probably do it better then bubble sort, but they will be `O(nlogn * |S|)`

However, sorting strings can be done in `O(n*|S|)` where `|S|` is the length of the average string, using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), and a simple [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

high-level pseudo code:

```
1. create a trie from your collection.
2. do a DFS on the trie generated, and add each string 
   to the list when you reach terminal node.
```

Comment: Do you know of any good (efficient) trie implementations in Python?

Comment: @Cameron: I am not really a native python user, so I do not. But I believe it exists, it is way too common, and python is way too widely used to believe there is no open-source implementation for it somewhere.

Answer (score 11):

Use the built-in `sort()` list method:

```
>>> words = [ 'baloney', 'aardvark' ]
>>> words.sort()
>>> print words
['aardvark', 'baloney']
```

It uses a `O(n lg(n))` sort<sup>1</sup>, the [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (which is a modified merge-sort, I believe. It's highly tuned for speed.).

---

<sup>1</sup> As pointed out in the comments, this refers to the number of element comparisons, not the number of low-level operations. Since the elements in this case are strings, and comparing two strings takes `min{|S1|, |S2|}` character comparisons, the total complexity is `O(n lg(n) * |S|)` where `|S|` is the length of the longest string being sorted. This is true of all comparison sorts, however -- the true number of operations varies depending on the cost of the element-comparison function for the type of elements being sorted. Since all comparison sorts use the same comparison function, you can just ignore this subtlety when comparing the algorithmic complexity of these sorts amongst each other.

Comment: any comparisons sorting algorithms are `O(nlogn * |S|)` for strings, since each compare op is not `O(1)`

Comment: @amit: True, though `|S|` is generally quite small compared to `n` for words. Tries are great, but constructing them (efficiently) is tricky, whereas `sort()` is a built-in.

Comment: @amit: they don't have to be; string equality testing can be done in `O(1)` time if the language performs string interning.

Comment: @ninjagecko: Sorts need a order comparison, not just "equal or not equal". Otherwise there's no way to tell if baloney should proceed aardvark. Interning only affects duplicate strings.

Comment: Cameron: I was referring to the `O(nlogn)` statement in your answer, it is just not true, *without additional assumptions*. Even if you assume `|S| = O(logn)`, you get `O(n(logn)^2)`. I agree however that using the built-in is the *simplest* way, but not the *fastest*, asymptotically. @ninjagecko: Is it done in python? how? any reference? I'd love to read it. [not being sarcastic here, I really am interested!]

Comment: @Cameron: You perform equality-testing at creation time of the string, testing it against the other strings in the intern pool whose hashes coincide. This isn't asymptotically much worse than creating the string (O(S)). If the string is equal to any existing string, return that string. When it comes time to compare strings, you can just see if the strings are `is`-equal (pointer/reference-equal). I think python does this because `'abc' is ('ab'+'c')` is True, which would cast doubts on amit's (at first-look quite reasonable) "string comparisons are O(S)" claim. You'd need to benchmark though.

Comment: @ninjagecko: String **order** comparisons *do* take `O(|S|)` operations. See my edited comment. Nobody cares if two strings are equivalent when sorting ;-)

Comment: @amit: Well, practically nothing is true without assumptions ;-) Traditionally, the big-O notation for sorts refers to the number of element comparisons, not the number of operations (which, I agree, is `O(n lg(n) * |S|)`) since that changes depending on what's being sorted.

Comment: @Cameron: oh oops, how silly of me. You can still achieve O(1) string sorting by keeping a sorted order on an interned string pool. Unfortunately this would lead to an asymptotic slowdown of string creation (at least for those in the pool), which would be bad... but it is possible. Albeit you don't get any work done "for free", so in the case where you only need to compare a pair of strings once, it is useless... but quite useful if you're doing so over-and-over again. Unfortunately sorts don't require that many string-comparisons on average (log(N) comparisons on average per string).

Comment: @Cameron: Now, after the edit that explains the complexity issue, I can +1 your answer, which for practical reasons [fast coding] is probably the best for *most* cases.

Comment: @amit: Thanks :-) I'll +1 yours for suggesting a better data structure.